# Razorpay response not sending Razorpay order_id

Tags: react-native

I am working on React Native Razorpay payment gateway integration.
I am using react-native-razorpay.

Code is below:-

Send Params are:-

```
var options = {
      description: "Credits towards consultation",
      image: "https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png",
      currency: "INR",
      key: "a-----b----ccc-dd",
      amount: Math.round(Number(order_total).toFixed(2) * 100),
      name: "Product",
      prefill: {
        email: email ? email : "v@razorpay.com",
        contact: mobile ? mobile : "1111111111",
        name:
          firstname && lastname
            ? `${firstname} ${lastname}`
            : "Razorpay Software"
      },
      theme: { color: theme.colors.primaryColor },

      payment_capture: 1
};
```

Checkout Method:-

```
RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
.then(data => {
  // handle success
  console.log("payment success", data);
  if (data && data.razorpay_payment_id) {
    orderData.payment = data.razorpay_payment_id;
    this.props.payMyOrder(orderData);
  }
})
.catch(error => {
  // handle failure
  this.toast.show(error.description);
});
```

I am getting only razorpay_payment_id in response but, razorpay_payment_id and razorpay_signature are missing. Also, in Razorpay backend Razorpay Order Id and Order Id are missing.

Comment: Suggested edit: you say you are getting only razorpay_payment_id and then you say that razorpay_payment_id is missing along with razorpay_signature. Something is not correct.

Answer (score 8):

hey as we can see in the above code options object that you are passing to the checkout you are not passing the order_id, you should pass the order_id as well. Since you are not passing the order_id the same is not getting returned to you after the payment is done. refer to the below link on how to create an order at your server-side.
https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/
if you pass the order_id in the request param to the checkout you'll get the order_id and signature as well in the payment response.

Comment: We can't directly pass the order id. We have to create the order firstly and then pass it to Razorpay.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation we need to pass the order_id, [here](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#create-an-order).

As per the documentation, once you pass the `order_id`, then only after payment successful razorpay returns the
`razorpay_order_id`,`razorpay_payment_id` and `razorpay_signature`.

After that you can compare the signature to get acknowledgement of payment success.

Comment: Yes first we need to create the order and then only we should pass the same created order_id to checkout method

Comment: the order id and signature is not being passed on successful payment that's the main issue

Answer (score 1):

Just a note if your id is wrong your `razorpaySignature` too will not appear

Answer (score 0):

Issue mostly will be because of invalid order Id, the order id received from Backend should be the one backend got from Razorpay.

Something like below should be used at your backend to generate order id `(format of order id will be order_<some id>)`. You can get language based backend implementation at this [link](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#create-an-order)

```
var instance = new Razorpay({ key_id: 'YOUR_KEY_ID', key_secret: 'YOUR_SECRET' })

instance.orders.create({
  amount: 50000,
  currency: "INR",
  receipt: "receipt#1",
  notes: {
    key1: "value3",
    key2: "value2"
  }
})
```